# Convert a string list to a true list in python

Tags: python

I have a python list but it comes to me as a string and i want to treat it as a list. How would i go about doing that?

So i get:

> "[[[-11828027,4726557],[-11820764,4723620],[-11819931,4711555],[-11829376,4710523],[-11828027,4726557]]]"

but i want to be able to work with it as if it were:

> [[[-11828027,4726557],[-11820764,4723620],[-11819931,4711555],[-11829376,4710523],[-11828027,4726557]]]

i have tried join and split but those don't really do what i want. I don't want to piece apart the list. I just want it to behave like a list and not a string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `ast` module's [`literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) method:

```
>>> import ast
>>> data = "[[[-11828027,4726557],[-11820764,4723620],[-11819931,4711555],[-11829376,4710523],[-11828027,4726557]]]"
>>> a_list = ast.literal_eval(data)
>>> a_list
[[[-11828027, 4726557], [-11820764, 4723620], [-11819931, 4711555], [-11829376, 4710523], [-11828027, 4726557]]]
>>> a_list[0]
[[-11828027, 4726557], [-11820764, 4723620], [-11819931, 4711555], [-11829376, 4710523], [-11828027, 4726557]]
>>> a_list[0][0]
[-11828027, 4726557]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use pythons eval()

```
YourList = eval("[[[-11828027,4726557],[-11820764,4723620],[-11819931,4711555],[-11829376,4710523],[-11828027,4726557]]]")
```

Comment: Please don't recommend eval without at least mentioning the potential for extreme danger: http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html